# Permission Error in Tag Friends in Open Graph Stories

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying post a Open Graph Story using a ShareOpenGraphContent and ShareApi.share in Android. That's work fine, but when I use setPeopleIds in content, I get a "Permissions error".

I already setup the Action Type to enable tags friends, but doesn't work.

Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

under your app in Status & Review the publish_actions permission should be require. And your application the publish_actions should be add to the login.
here is a java example with facebook Login button

```
    final List<String> actionPermission = new LinkedList<String>();
    actionPermission.add("publish_actions");
    buttonLoginFacebook.setPublishPermissions(actionPermission);
```

see Login https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login?locale=pt_BR